# How to update an binary values array if the distance between two same values is less than 5?

Tags: python, arrays, replace, binary

I am jumbling with one usecase in python coding.

**Question:**

I have an array having binary values like `[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]`. Now I have to replace all the values by `1` in between two ones (1's)  if the distance between them (1's)  is less than `5`.

For example, The index of the first `1` is `4` and the index of the second times occurrence of `1` is `7`, so the distance between these two occurrences of 1's is `3` which is less than `5` (as per condition) therefore, We will replace all the values in between these two ones by 1.

Similarly, we have to do it for each value of the array.

Example **:** `[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1]`

Desired output **:**

```
[0,0,0,0,1,**1,1**,1,**1**,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,**1**,1,1,1,**1,1,1,1**,1,1]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this question [checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def insert_ones(bit_stream):
    new_bit_stream = bit_stream.copy()
    last_one_idx = -1
    for idx, bit in enumerate(bit_stream):
        if last_one_idx == -1:
            if bit == 1:
                last_one_idx = idx
        else:
            if bit == 1:
                length = idx - last_one_idx
                if length < 6:
                    new_bit_stream[last_one_idx : idx] = [1] * length
                last_one_idx = idx
    return new_bit_stream
```

You can replace `new_bit_stream` with `bit_stream` if you want to mutate the stream in place

Comment: Yes, sure i did